# Please tell users not to use the elementary.io tag when not abput the website

Tags: discussion

A week's ago (or a month) I removed questions not about the website from the elementary.io tag.

Now again the tag is filled with questions not about the website.I can't be cleaning it all the time.

What should we do

Answer (score 1):

Renaming [elementary.io](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary.io) to something like [elementary-website](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-website) (with "elementary.io" as an alias) would appear to be a friendlier solution for new users. If they go to type in "elementary", it will be clear that the website tag is not what they want, while those who type in the ".io" suffix will still get what they intended.

Comment: I've changed elementary.io to elementary-website, but I don't think you'll find it helps. It will still be the default selection when people hit enter.